# Slave smokeping on xen VM shows substantial packet loss

Tags: linux, networking, xen, ping, icmp

I am using a Xen VM instance as a smokeping host. Recently I added a second XEN VM (on different iron, about 200 Km away) with smokeping in slave configuration. This is - again - a Xen VM, with a similar configuration to its master. While the smokeping instance is running, substantial packet losses are being reported (smokeping **and** CLI ping) - all the while, sibling nodes on the same iron and vbridge and the DomU itaself are reporting no packet loss. Turning off smokeping, the fake packet loss disappears (but so does my remote network probe). I dicked around with the (few) ICMP related kernel parameters without any change ( kernel is `2.6.32-642.15.1.el6.i686` on a CentOS6)

What do?

T.I.A.

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is - never trust the anti-ICMP flood rules/engine on your firewall to Do The Right Thing.  It does not.